# ConnectorStore changes in Bot Builder SDK 3.5.5?

Tags: c#, botframework

I’m upgrading Bot Builder SDK for our bot from 3.5.0 to 3.5.5 due to LUIS endpoint being deprecated in few weeks and it seems like latest SDK version has a way to specify ‘LuisApiVersion’.

During upgrade, I’m getting following error while modifying the behavior to use LastWriteWins policy for CachingBotDataStoreConsistencyPolicy:

Exception thrown:

> 'Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException' in autofac.dll
>
> Additional information: The requested service 'Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ConnectorStore' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.

```
        builder.Register(c => new CachingBotDataStore(c.Resolve<ConnectorStore>(),
            CachingBotDataStoreConsistencyPolicy.LastWriteWins)
            .As<IBotDataStore<BotData>>()                           
            .AsSelf()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

This code has worked for 3.5.0, but I’m not sure what’s the best way to handle the Autofac error that we are getting with 3.5.5. Any pointers or idea about this?

Answer (score 3):

The registration of ConnectorStore has changed as you can see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Autofac/Dialogs/DialogModule.cs#L148).

To solve the issue you should change the `c.Resolve<ConnectorStore>()` in the your code to `c.ResolveKeyed<IBotDataStore<BotData>>(typeof(ConnectorStore))`